How to access assets with external calls from another server in symfony 6 (in prod-env)?
I set up two seperate local servers for test purposes. One is pretty much only accessing the other and calling a route that displays some images. When the target server is running in dev-mode, it works perfectly fine, but when i put it to prod, i get 404-messages for every asset.
The target server is rendering a twig template that includes the images via asset('...') from the local file system. Why is that the case and how to i prevent that?
The twig template is pretty basic (extending the base.html.twig which is untouched):
<div class="container" style="background-image: url({{ asset('sub_img/backgrounds/playercard_bg_6w.png') }})">
    <div class="player-image-container" style="background-image: url({{ asset(player.photoPath) }})">
        <div class="club-logo" style="background-image: url({{ asset(player.clubIconPath) }})"></div>
        <div class="nation-logo" style="background-image: url({{ asset(player.nationIconPath) }})"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-container">
    </div>
    <div class="player-name-banner">
        <span>{{ player.name }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="stats-table-container">
        {% for key,val in player.best6 %}
            {% if loop.index == 1 or loop.index == 4 %}
            <div class="stats-table">
            {% endif %}
                <div class="stat-container"><span class="stat-label">{{key}}</span><span class="stat-value">{{ val }}</span></div>
            {% if loop.index == 3 or loop.index == 6 %}
            <div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

All of the asset-variables like player.nationIconPath have pathes similar to the following:
'sub_img/backgrounds/playercard_bg_6w.png'
In dev-eEvironment it works fine, in prod i get the 404 messages for every asset (including standard symfony assets like bootstrap.js which i didnt even touch). In browser, the route works fine, even in prod, just not if called from my other webserver. Or rather the route matches, just the assets are gone.
It is a very small project that i just set up and did hardly anything for config or anything that would differ from the symfony-webapp-skeleton.
I'd be very grateful for any help!
